# Windows 7: connection-specific DNS suffix is present but DHCP server does not providing it

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am connecting to home network with dummy DHCP server which is providing only IPv4 address, subnet mask and gateway, but when I run ipconfig /all I see, that there is set connection-specific DNS suffix of some network I connected in past. This is weird, because on the basis of DNS suffix is set firewall profile.

Some hints:

- Network whose DNS suffix persist in settings of my wireless connection was IPv6 only
- When I disable IPv6, DNS suffix disappears
- I am connected to home network by Wi-Fi and by ethernet (same DHCP server), but DNS suffix is present only on Wi-Fi
- When I restart computer, DNS suffix is gone and good firewall profile is selected, but when I disable adapter and enable again, suffix is back (same when going to sleep)
- Same suffix is present on isatap adapter

Thank you in advance

Comment: which part of this is an actual question?

Comment: Question is why is connection-specifix DNS suffix set though DHCP server did not providing it.

Comment: You should be able to explicitly configure the DNS suffix via the Advanced TCP/IP properties for the adapter.